Prolog order of clause body gives different results when using negation
I am struggling to understand why swapping the two body clauses gives different results when one of the clauses is a negation.
married(john).
male(john).
male(kev).

bachelor1(X) :- \+ married(X), male(X).
bachelor2(X) :- male(X), \+ married(X).

bachelor1(X). doesn't find any atom.
bachelor2(X). finds kev.

What do you expect \+ married(X) to produce, when X is var?

I expected the same result kev for both bachelor rules and I dont understand why they are different

The operator \+ (mnemonic: ⊬) implements a non-monotonic inference rule (known as negation as failure) that expresses logical negation only for ground goals. According to this rule, \+(G) is true only if goal G cannot be proven. In other words, to prove \+(G), Prolog first tries to prove G and then:

If the proof of G succeeds, the proof of \+(G) fails;
If the proof of G fails, the proof of \+(G) succeeds.

As we can see, both predicates bachelor1/1 and bachelor2/1 work as expected for queries without variables:
?- bachelor1(john).
false.

?- bachelor1(kev).
true.

?- bachelor2(john).
false.

?- bachelor2(kev).
true.

In fact, the problem only occurs with queries containing variables. To understand the difference between bachelor1/1 and bachelor2/1, analyze the following Prolog search trees:

In the first version, the negated goal to be proven is not ground (thus, the predicate does not work as expected).



In the second version, the negated goal to be proven is ground (thus, the predicate does work as expected).



Let's use P (meaning Person), rather than vague X.
\+ married(P) was intended to mean "P is not married", but it actually means "married(P) cannot succeed".
However, married(P) can succeed, because P is var and can unify with john.
So, \+ married(P) fails, so Prolog does not continue on to male(X).
The fix is to make sure that P is sufficiently instantiated (which for atoms means being ground, i.e. fully instantiated, i.e. having a value with no var components) before using \+ - here is an example of sufficient instantiation using terms, where the term name is sufficient:
married(person(john)).

This works as intended if we say "no fish are married":
?- \+ married(fish(F)).
true.

... because the term names are different (fish vs person) and cannot unify.
